# Linux service approaches

Tags: c++, linux, unix, windows-services

I need to implement a windows-like service for Linux system. There is C++ code which do a particular job which I want to be run by schedule (every minute).

The service will be always up and running 24h/day, 7d/week and 365d/year and should be highly fault tolerant.

What is the best suitable approach to implement such service? Daemon, Linux service, cron e.t.c or some combination of them?

Comment: Cron every minute sounds silly, just implement a daemon. There is no standardized "linux service api" as there is for windows, and no obvious equivalent of svchost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally do that using either a cron job or a daemon, but not both.

> There is C++ code which do a particular job which I want to be run by schedule (every minute).

That sounds like a candidate for a cron job. If you need to keep a lot of state in between invocations though, a daemon with a 1-minute timer in it could be a better option.

You may like to provide more details on what your application is supposed to do.

Comment: additional info: the service should be run under root permissions, so it is highly privileged

Comment: @ohavryl: that doesn't change much.